# Selenium / PhantomJS: Button isn't clicked

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to automate website interaction in Python with Selenium using PhantomJS as a driver. I've got everything working as it should except for the final button click which is apparently executed but doesn't perform the action it does when I manually click it. In fact, it does nothing at all.

Here is my code for locating the element and clicking it (I've tried several other approaches like xpath, class_name, css_selector, using the .click() action...). I decided to stick with the JS click approach since this works perfectly fine when I execute it using the browser console.

```
await_element2 = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_id"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 300, 10).until(await_element2)
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("element_id").click()')
```

Here is the html source code of the element in question:

```
<span style="top:30;left:0;" class="part1 part2" id="element_id" data-type="type" data-bundle="3">text</span>
```

One thing I noticed is that the ghostdriver.log mentions some errors that are related to the script the button should interact/execute when clicked.

```
[ERROR - 2017-04-24T12:43:11.022Z] Session - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Audio

[ERROR - 2017-04-24T12:43:11.022Z] Session - page.onError - stack: global code (https://url.com/script.js?v1.2:6)
```

It seems PhantomJS doesn't support the audio tags but I'm not sure how to solve this for Python and I don't know what to do with the second error. For reference, I'm running this on a headless Raspberry Pi.

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: I "solved" this by using Firefox as the webdriver. PhantomJS is at fault I guess.